# Excel RTD Server unable to update file

Tags: c#, excel, dde

We are developing real time data manipulation system, and in some business of it we need to migrate some data to Excel and that data must be updated simultaneously according to system data.

We used the Excel RTD Server for this purpose as following:

- There is an RtdServer DLL
- Used `regasm.exe` tool to register the dll file
- Creating a message according to RTD format `=RTD("ProgIDName",,"xxxx","yyy")`

*But unfortunately in Excel the data is not updated.*

By performing search about issue there were no current results and most of the topics suggested that there may be an issue in registering the server DLL. Are there any missed steps to perform? What can I do to ensure Excel RTD Server works?

Thanks in advance and best regards,